# Convert typedef to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, typedef, code-conversion, type-alias

How do I convert this code to Swift

```
 typedef  UIViewController<CalendarViewControllerNavigation> CalendarViewController;
```

tried to find solution everywhere but seems I can't find a reference to this.

Comment: You used the `typealias` tag for your question. So you seem to already know the answer.

Comment: Swift doesn't currently support expressing the type of something that inherits from a class and conforms to a given protocol – but [it will in a future version of the language](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md).

Comment: Do you any other way I can do that. Maybe create extension of UIViewController pressing protocol the typealias to that extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 4 you can use:

```
typealias CalendarViewController = UIViewController & CalendarViewControllerNavigation
```

Which uses the new [protocol composition type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID454).
Also see [SE-156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue to use calendar library from https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar.

I have solved this problem as below.

```
protocol CalendarViewControllerNavigation: NSObjectProtocol {
    func move(to date: Date, animated: Bool)
}

typealias CalendarTypeController = UIViewController

extension CalendarTypeController:CalendarViewControllerNavigation{
    internal func move(to date: Date, animated: Bool) {
    }
    internal func deviceIsRotated() {
    }
    internal func selectedEventForAddSession(event:EventDetail) {
    }
}


protocol CalenderViewControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func calendarViewController(_ controller:CalendarTypeController, showDate:NSDate)
}
```

Hope this code will help you!